# Incompatible results in finding the variance of random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, descriptive-statistics

Let $f(x) = 3/64(2x - 2)$ whenever $x \in [1, 5]$, zero otherwise, be the PDF of a random var. I know the expected value of $X$ is $2.75$. I was asked to find its variance. For the sake of practice I used two methods. First, I calculated $E(X^2)$ and used the fact that $V(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$. This gives

\begin{align*}
    \frac{3}{64}\int_1^5 (2x -2)x^2 ~ dx &= \frac{3}{64}\int_1^5 x^2(2x) - 2x^2
    ~ dx \\ 
                                         &= \frac{3}{64} \left(  \int_1^{25}  u
                                         ~ du - 2\int_1^5 x^2 ~ dx \right)
                                         & \{u = x^2\} \\ 
                                         &= \frac{3}{64} \left( \left(
                                         \frac{25^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right) -
                                     2 \left( \frac{5^3}{3} - \frac{1}{3}
                                 \right) \right)  \\ 
                                         &= \frac{3}{64} \left( 312 - 
                                         \frac{248}{3} \right)  \\ 
                                         &= 10.75
\end{align*}

Online calculators confirm this result. From this should follow that $V(X) = 10.75 - 2.75^2 = 3.1875$.

Now, via direct definition of the variance, one obtains (I skip the steps, but one can confirm with online calculators)

$$
V(X) = \frac{3}{64}\int_1^5 (2x-2)(x-2.75)^2 ~ dx = 1.296875
$$

The results should be the same. My error cannot be one of calculation, because both integrals are correctly solved according to online calculators. It seems I am wrong in expecting that this identity holds:

$$
\int_{1}^{5} f(x)(x- E(X)) ~ dx = E(X^2) - E(X)^2
$$

But this is a standard property. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not using a PDF. Note that $$\int_1^5 (3/64)(2x-2)dx=3/4 \neq 1$$

Comment: Jesus... I've double checked now and the "PDF" of the problem sheet is exactly the one I gave. Must be a typo by the professors. I didn't even think to check. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: My name is Michael. =)